# Open scrapy output in browser tab or ipython window

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on my first spider after doing the scrapy tut:

```
class My_Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "My_Spider"


    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1):
            yield Request('my_url', method="post", headers= headers, body=payload, callback=self.parse_method)


    def parse_method(self,response):
        print(response.body)
```

Is there a way to open the response body in a browser window tab or ipython notebook?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is an [`open_in_browser()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#open-in-browser) built into Scrapy utility function:

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

open_in_browser(response)
```

Comment: Holy crap I didn't know about this function, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Open in browser`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#open-in-browser)
Example from the documentation:

```py
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

def parse_details(self, response):
    if "item name" not in response.body:
        open_in_browser(response)
```

For your problem it will be like:

```py
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
open_in_browser(response)
```

Also, we can see a web page use `scrapy shell`.
For example:

```sh
scrapy shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465387/open-scrapy-output-in-browser-tab-or-ipython-window
```

and then view the response in a browser

```sh
view(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

To open the response object in a specific browser

```py
import webbrowser
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

open_in_browser(response, _openfunc=webbrowser.get('/path/to/browser/exe').open)
```